# Quotation mark in C#

Tags: c#

How can I get Quotation mark by giving the ascii number in C#?

I tried to use `(char)34` but it returns `\"` sign. How can I omit the back slash sign and have just quotation mark as an string?

Comment: Show your code please. The backlash is there to escape double quotes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 7):

You are doing this correctly. When you see the backslash, it's because you're viewing the value via the debugger which displays the escaped versions of strings. If you do `Console.WriteLine((char)34)`, you'll see that the quotation mark is outputted correctly into the console window.